# How are Jenkins manual Git tags used?

Tags: git, deployment, continuous-integration, jenkins

I can click the "No Tags" icon on any of my builds and create a new tag but Jenkins doesn't push it to the origin server.  So what's the point?

With Git, I understand Jenkins can do a pre-build merge and upon success tag it and push to origin (which I do have working) but I can't specify a descriptive tag because the builds are initiated two different ways...

1. **By Git hook on every commit to origin** - the Jenkins job builds and publishes to a development server continuously.  In this case the tag is some auto-generated value (e.g. jenkins-build-$BUILD_NUMBER), which isn't much help and I'd rather not tag every single commit.
2. **Manual build** - in this case I want the developer to tag their last build in Jenkins with an appropriate value (e.g. 1.0.3) and then choose to deploy that tag to another environment... but how?

This worked very well with Subversion (there's even a great little plugin that shows the last 10 SVN tags in a drop down) but I can't seem to accomplish it with Git.